# JS Function is invoked but no result

Tags: javascript, function

When I invoke the function it is getting invoked but it flashes the result. Could please tell me what is the mistake I did?

Below is the HTML Code I used:

**I have replaced the input type as a button but still, error not fixed.**

```js
function reg() {
  //Name Field
  var f = document.forms["registration"]["fullname"].value;
  if (f == "") {
    alert("Enter the name");
    return false;
  } else if (!f.match(/^.[a-zA-Z]+$/))

  {
    alert("Enter only alphabets");
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "Hi" + registration.fullname.value;
}
```

```html
<form name="registration" onsubmit="return reg()">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. Where is the `details` element?

Comment: You're submitting a form, which will send the data back to the server and cause a page reload (therefore clearing the `details` element again) - did you intend to send the data back to the server?

Comment: If not, move the return false to the end

Comment: Also you meant to do  `"HI"+f;` - Press F12 and fix the console errors

Comment: Or if you're just playing around, switch from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: @Adelin It's more complex than just doing that - the whole function is off the back of the `onsubmit` of the `form`.  There's some confusion in probably both what the OP wants to achieve and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I *believe* you want to do.

Note it is better to add an event handler in the script rather than having an inline handler, but for now I pass the form itself in the function

```js
function reg(form) {
  //Name Field
  var f = form.fullname.value;
  if (f == "") {
    alert("Enter the name");
    return false;
  }

  // no need for else when you return

  if (!f.match(/^[\. a-zA-Z]+$/)) { // I personally have a space in my full name
    alert("Enter only alphabets and space");
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "Hi " + f;
  // change to true if you want to submit the form but you will then not be able to see the HI
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="registration" onsubmit="return reg(this)">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<span id="details"></span>
```

Comment: This is the fine example and the answer as well.